# How to include a combo in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a view that was created through the scaffold. One of the fields is a foreign key from another table. How do I make a combobox for this field with the information from this table ?

Below is showing as it is nowin view :
    <%= f.number_field :workflow_id %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exemple into the view:
%>`<%= select_tag(:workflow, options_for_select(collection_for_select(@workflows, :name, :id), @workflow.id)) %>`

Answer (score 0):

The form helper method you want to use is f.select, or one of his variants. You'll find happiness in here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/